# Como usar o operador %<>% em R

Tags: r, operadores

1. O que significa o operador  `%<>%` em R ?
2. Qual a sua diferença em relação a `<-` ?
3. Em que circunstâncias ele pode ser útil?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse operador é do pacote `magrittr` e ele serve para você passar um objeto para uma função ao mesmo tempo modificando o objeto que você passou.

Por exemplo, suponha o seguinte `x` em formato de texto:

```
library(magrittr)    
x <- "1"
```

Suponha que você queira converter esse `x` para numérico. Uma forma de fazer isso é atribuir a `x` o resultado da função `as.numeric` nele mesmo:

```
x <- as.numeric(x)
```

Com o `%<>%` você faz a mesma coisa sem precisar escrever o `x` duas vezes, pois o operador `%<>%` passa o `x` para o `as.numeric` e depois reescreve `x`:

```
x %<>% as.numeric # mesma coisa de x <- x %>% as.numeric
```

Ou seja, enquanto o `<-` apenas modifica a variável da esqueda com a expressão da direita, o `%<>%` modifica a variável da esquerda após passar essa variável para uma função que está na direita.

No fundo isso é uma questão de sintaxe, tal como o `%>%`.